Can a static JSON API be used with Microsoft Copilot Studio?
I'm using a Power Apps custom connector to connect a static JSON API hosted at https://fabricembeddedreport.azurewebsites.net/tapal-test/jsontest.json. While it works with Azure Functions, it's not functioning with this static API when trying to link it to Copilot Studio. Is this expected behavior? What are the requirements or limitations for static APIs with Copilot Studio?
